# results button disappear and condition code not working

Tags: python, tkinter, button, conditional-statements

I am new to Python and I have not been able to resolve this issue for more than 1 week. Each time, I try to insert a code with condition e.g if result is =zero, print(' reorder') or any codes, the result button disappear. The condition code also does not work. How should I write the condition code so that it works and also ensure that the result button does not disappear. Thanks. Below is my code:

```
#import tkinter module
import tkinter as tk

#initialise the window manager
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Inventory system menu")
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=400, width=500, bg="White")
frame=tk.Frame(root, bg="green")
frame.place(relwidth=0.9, relheight=0.9, relx=0.05, rely=0.05)

#define label widget
tk.Label(frame, font=("Helvetica", 20), text="Quantity:").grid(row=0)
tk.Label(frame, font=("Helvetica", 20), text="Price:").grid(row=1,column=0)
tk.Label(frame, font=("Helvetica", 20), text="Category:").grid(row=2,column=0)
tk.Label(frame, font=("Helvetica", 20), text="Description:").grid(row=3,column=0)

# define entry variables
Quantity = tk.StringVar()
Price = tk.StringVar()

# assign the StringVar to the entry widget text variables
Quantity= tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=Quantity)
Quantity.grid(row=0, column=1)
Price= tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=Price)
Price.grid(row=1, column=1)
Category= tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=Category)
Category.grid(row=2, column=1)
Description= tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=Description)
Description.grid(row=3, column=1)

#formula (relationship between quantity and price)
def generate():
  
  result = float(Quantity.get()) * float(Price.get())
  print(result)
  #result widget
generate=tk.Button(frame, text="result", height="2", width="8", fg="Black", bg="yellow",command=generate)
generate.grid(row=4, column=2)

#geometric management pack
canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You shouldn't use the same variable name for multiple things. Also in your case there is no point to the `StringVar`s because you can just use `<tk.Entry>.get()`

Comment: Your code is throwing an error: `Category= tk.Entry(frame, textvariable=Category) NameError: name 'Category' is not defined`. textvariable Category is not defined (same for textvariable=Description). Did you get this error too, or is your code incomplete here?

Comment: @TheLizzard - i receive invalid syntax when i type Quantity = <tk.Entry>.get()

Comment: @Learner You need to replace the `<tk.Entry>` with your entry. I was just showing that it was a `tkinter` `Entry` object and that you call call `.get()`

Comment: @8349697. You are right. I just added
 Quantity = tk.StringVar()
Price = tk.StringVar()
Category= tk.StringVar()
Description=tk.StringVar()
and it eradicates 'Category not defined' error.

Comment: So now you see your button?

Comment: @8349697. As long as i don't change or add any code , the button remains and gives the result for Quantity*Price. It disappears when i  add additional codes

Comment: Look, when I run your code, it throws a NameError, but the root window is displayed. Due to an error, the code below `Price.grid(row=1, column=1)` is not executed. Not all window elements are displayed. I can't see the Entries (Category, Description) and result button. Perhaps the fact that the root window is displayed (despite the error) is misleading you that the button disappears? If you add code (which generates errors) before creating the button, it will disappear.

Comment: You use the same names for different objects. For example, there is a function called `generate` and the variable for a button is also called `generate`. This could potentially lead to unexpected side effects. Your example does not have a part of the code with conditions. So it is not clear what exactly is causing you difficulties with the code.

Comment: I had delete and edit some of the codes and it is finally working.Thanks for your help.